# How to find un-ordered numbers (lineal search)

Tags: c++, performance, search

A **list partially ordered** of n numbers is given and I have to find those numbers that does not follow the order (just find them and count them).

- There are no repeated numbers.
- There are no negative numbers.
- `MAX = 100000` is the capacity of the list.
- `n`, the number of elements in the list, is given by the user.

Example of two lists:

`1 2 5 6 3`

`1 6 2 9 7 4 8 10 13`

For the first list the **output is 2** since 5 and 6 should be both after 3, they are unordered; for the second the **output is 3** since 6, 9 and 7 are out of order.

The most important condition in this problem: **do the searching in a linear way O(n)** or being quadratic the worst case.

Here is part of the code I developed (however it is no valid since it is a quadratic search).

**"unordered" function** compares each element of the array with the one given by "minimal" function; if it finds one bigger than the minimal, that element is unordered.

```
int unordered (int A[MAX], int n)
int cont = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    if (A[i] > minimal(A, n, i+1)){
        count++;
    }
}

return count;
```

**"minimal" function** takes the minimal of all the elements in the list between the one which is being compared  in "unordered" function and the last of the list. `i < elements <= n` . Then, it is returned to be compared.

```
int minimal (int A[MAX], int n, int index)
int i, minimal = 99999999;


for (i = index; i < n; i++){
    if (A[i] <= minimo)
        minimal = A[i];
}

return minimal;
```

How can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: what would be the output for `1 6 2 9 7 4 8 11 12 10 13` ? is `12` out of order because `11` is out of order or not? or is `10` out of order?

Comment: Homework alert.

Comment: In that case `6 9 7 11 12 13`are out of order. 11 and 12 are out of order since 8 is the closest one to 10

Comment: Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum.  It is a question an answer site. Read the [faq] and [ask]. Do not edit your question to insert your solution, post an _answer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start on the left of the list and compare the current number you see with the next one. Whenever the next is smaller than the current remove the current number from the list and count one up. After removing a number at index 'n' set your current number to index 'n-1' and go on.

Because you remove at most 'n' numbers from the list and compare the remaining in order, this Algorithmus in O(n).

I hope this helps. I must admit though that the task of finding numbers that are out of of order isn't all that clear.

Comment: But, what happen in this case?: `1 5 6 3`.5 and 6 are unordered since they should be after 3.

Comment: Absolutely right. In this case you discover that 6 is bigger than 3, remove 6 und go back to 5 (index n-1). Then you compare 5 to 3, which is again bigger. So you remove 5, Go to 1, compare it and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If O(n) space is no problem, you can first do a linear run (backwards) over the array and save the minimal value so far in another array. Instead of calling minimal you can then look up the minimum value in O(1) and your approach works in O(n).

Something like this:

```
int min[MAX]; //or: int *min = new int[n];
min[n-1] = A[n-1];
for(int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i)
    min[i] = min(A[i], min[i+1]);
```

Can be done in O(1) space if you do the first loop backwards because then you only need to remember the current minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested some great answers, but I have an extra way you can think of this problem. Using a **stack**.

Here's how it helps: Push the leftmost element in the array onto the stack. Keep doing this until the element you are currently at (on the array) is less than top of the stack. While it is, pop elements and increment your counter. Stop when it is greater than top of the stack and push it in. In the end, when all array elements are processed you'll get the count of those that are out of order.

Sample run: `1 5 6 3 7 4 10`

Step 1: Stack => **1**

Step 2: Stack => **1 5**

Step 3: Stack => **1 5 6**

Step 4: Now we see 3 is in. While 3 is less than top of stack, pop and increment counter. We get: Stack=> **1 3** -- Count = 2

Step 5: Stack => **1 3 7**

Step 6: We got 4 now. Repeat same logic. We get: Stack => **1 3 4** -- Count = 3

Step 7: Stack => **1 3 4 10** -- Count = 3. And we're done.

This should be O(N) for time and space. Correct me if I'm wrong.